# SignalR working only first time when put code in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, master-pages

I am putting `signalR` code in `masterpage.aspx`. like this

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>        
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>  
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    function GetChat() {
        var chat = $.connection.notificationHub;
        return chat;
    }
    function OnStartHub(loginID) {            
        var chat = GetChat();
        chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {

            alert(message);
        };           
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {             
            var loginID = clienthiddenUserID.Get("UserID");
            var loginname = clienthiddenUserID.Get("UserName");
            $.connection.hub.qs = "name=" + loginID + "";
            chat.server.receive(loginID, loginname);
        });
    }
    $(function () {

        OnStartHub();

        setTimeout(ReceiveNoti, 10000);
    });
    function ReceiveNoti() {
       // alert("Enter Receive");
        var chat = GetChat();
        var loginID = clienthiddenUserID.Get("UserID");
        var loginname = clienthiddenUserID.Get("UserName");
        chat.server.receive(loginID, loginname);
        setTimeout(ReceiveNoti, 10000);
    }
```

This works good when i login into my application and `default.aspx` load. But when i move to another page like `Users.aspx` it thrown me error in js saying

```
Unhandled exception at line 18, column 13 in http://localhost:49483/Targets.aspx

 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'notificationHub' of undefined or null reference
```

Comment: you have added script reference as `<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>` so referance is relative to that specific page, change it to `<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>` so it will be relative to base and scripts will load

Answer (score 0):

you have added script reference as `<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>` so referance is relative to that specific page, change it to `<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>` so it will be relative to base and scripts will load.

Comment: Just one question, to confirm, you added slash(/) to all the scripts instead of only signalr/hubs, right? Because its definitely path issue

Comment: Yupp i just added slash to `/signalR/hubs`

Comment: No, i mean all 3 scripts need slash, if not try "~/" ` <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>        
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>  
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>`

Comment: Other scripts like jquery in same folder loading without adding ~ or /.  problem might be something else

Comment: Issue was something very strange.  I have added some css reference in masterpage.. accidently i have added the same in content page. removing reference from content page does the trick .